# Does MSSQL always copy tables when using Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

After googling and looking into the MS documenation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) on linked servers I still couldn't get a clear answer to the following question. I'm thinking about linking 2 SQL Servers so I can create a subset of data from the source DB and insert it into an output DB (with duplicate checks before inserting) but I don't know how MSSQL processes queries that use linked databases.

As far as I know following query will result in LocalServer downloading the FarAwayTable and then executing the query locally (which is killing for performance in my case):

```
SELECT 
    f.* 
FROM 
    FarAwayServer.FarAwayDB.dbo.FarAwayTable f, 
    LocalServer.LocalDb.dbo.LocalTable l
WHERE
    f.ID = l.ID
```

My question is, will MSSQL do the same for the following query or will it only download the result (executing the whole query on the FarAwayServer):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    FarAwayServer.FarAwayDB.dbo.FarAwayTable f
WHERE
    f.ID = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will still act the same (the *FarAwayTable* table will be downloaded and the query will be executed locally). If you want to execute the query on *FarAwayServer* you should use [OPENQUERY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx):

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([FarAwayServer], 'SELECT * FROM FarAwayDB.dbo.FarAwayTable f WHERE f.ID = 1')
```

Comment: Thanks, gues I'll have to write queries without parameters ( OPENQUERY/OPENROWSET) ;).

Comment: @Rob Believe me I know the pain, also you need to be especially careful regarding the security in order to avoid injections.

Comment: Well atleast the inserts can be written without OPENQUERY :)